# Exchange Push Notifications between 2 Apps with different App Ids as part of Chat feature:iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I'm working on a App, which will have two separate packages "Business" and "Customer". 
I have implemented "Push Notification" for "Business" and which are working just fine.

Now, I am trying to do the same for the "Customer" App. The basic functionality is to implement chatting between two Apps.

Now,that the two Apps are going to have two different App Ids, is it possible to exchange Push Notification between them ?

**Precisely:- suppose Business" has AppId "com.example.business" and 'Customer" has AppId "com.example.cutomer" now each of these AppIds will have their own APNS certificates and Profiles.**

I want to learn is, Is it possible to make a chat functionality using Push notifications in such scenario ?

Any help will be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

YES you could do this but. This should be done on server side. 
 1. You need at least a webservice called from the application to the
    server.
 2. The server should identify the source (by a parameter or you can do two webservices) of the webservice call and send a push notification to the other application.